# Would enchanting an opponents Stuffy Doll with Pariah cause a Draw?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm not sure how I haven't stumbled upon this amazing combo of cards before! I was just thinking, would it cause an infinite loop if I controlled a [Pariah](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPariah%5d) that was attached to an opponents [Stuffy Doll](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=279711)?

In turn would this be a draw?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that would be a draw as soon as any damage would be dealt to you or the Stuffy Doll, assuming that you are the chosen player for Stuffy Doll.

Once damage would be dealt to you or Stuffy Doll, that damage is dealt to Stuffy Doll. Then Stuffy Doll's triggered ability triggers and it tries to deal damage to you, but it deals that damage to itself instead, which triggers its ability again. This creates an infinite loop, which results in a draw because of [rule 719.4](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Taking_shortcuts):

> If a loop contains only mandatory actions, the game is a draw. (See rules 104.4b and 104.4f.)

Comment: That's a mental combo though... I'm tempted to invest in both of those cards just for the sheer unfriendliness of it... haha

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that if you control the Stuffy Doll, it's better to just name your opponent with its ability. Pariah still works well with Stuffy Doll, but setting up this combo on your own is probably more trouble than it's worth just to end the game with a draw.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that haha I was just looking for a contingency if i ever faced it.